# How to avoid paradox of DDL trigger notifying of dropped triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2014

This is more of a philosophical question than a programmatic one.  I have been tasked with implementing various and sundry security enhancements to our MS SQL 2014 servers.  I have a simple trigger as follows....

```
CREATE TRIGGER send_db_email_notification 
ON ALL SERVER 
AFTER   CREATE_DATABASE, 
        ALTER_DATABASE, 
        DROP_DATABASE, 
        CREATE_FUNCTION, 
        ALTER_FUNCTION,
        CREATE_TRIGGER,
        ALTER_TRIGGER,
        DROP_TRIGGER
AS 
-- do stuff to send mail
ENABLE TRIGGER send_db_email_notification ON ALL SERVER
```

The trigger works as expected.  I receive an email when one of the events is fired.  Well, it does whenever a DB is created, altered or dropped, or a function is created or altered.  The problem is the `drop_trigger` event.

If someone comes in and drops this same trigger, it cannot execute itself to notify that it was dropped, because it no longer exists.  In other words, the trigger cannot signal its own deletion.  At least that is what I assume is happening.

What is the best way to test whether or not my trigger that tests for trigger deletions is not itself deleted?  Am I really supposed to create a second trigger to test for trigger deletions, so that if either one gets deleted, the other one can still fire?  That seems rather awkward and clunky, not to mention I would get two notifications if some other trigger was deleted, unless I coded the second trigger to specifically only look for deletion of the first.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this scenario?

Comment: What kind of security it is if anyone can drop SERVER level objects?

Comment: *"the trigger cannot signal its own deletion"* >> Have you tested that?

Comment: The point is that nobody should ever be able to drop a server level object.  In other words, the object is that this trigger should never fire.  At least that's the idea.  Yes, I have tested this.  It's possible I have done something wrong in my testing, but I don't believe so, as all of the other events work as expected.

Comment: If someone can drop this trigger - what would prevent him from disabling it before?

Comment: Besides, attempting to send email right here, inside the trigger does not look like a great idea: sendmail can raise an exception (so DDL will fail), server may fail to send it physically without any exception (so you'll never know).

Comment: As I said, this question has less of a programming angle, and more of a "how do I handle this" aspect.  A security expert I am not.  It seemed logical to me that creating a trigger to fire off email for events that were not supposed to be occurring as an in-your-face alert besides server audit was a reasonable approach.  If not, I am clearly open to suggestions on a better approach.